# How to print specific letter from the word and leave the other letters '_' (Hangman)

Tags: python

I am making a game called hangman where you have to guess the letter one by one before the person dies, which takes seven tries...So before seven tries you have to guess the word, I am not sure how to show the word the user has guessed and remove the ones which he haven't

Eg- The word to Guess : DREAM

user guess a character :  A

so it should output:    _ _ _ A _

Here is my code

```
print ("WELCOME TO HANGMAN")
letter=input("TYPE A WORD--> ")
letter.upper()
NO = len(letter)
for letters in range (0,NO):
    print ("_")
for chance in range (1,7):
    UI=input("Type a letter")
    if UI.find(letter):
        print (letter)
```

Comment: The code isn't indented correctly; please fix.

Comment: Indentation problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list and character comparison

```
print ("WELCOME TO HANGMAN")
letter=input("TYPE A WORD--> ")
letter = letter.upper()
NO = len(letter)
word_ = '_'*NO
print (word_)

for chance in range (1,7):
    UI=input("Type a letter")
    UI = UI.upper()
    word_ = list(word_)
    UI_pos= [pos for pos, char in enumerate(letter) if char == UI]
     for pos in UI_pos:
        word_[pos] = UI
    word_ = ''.join(word_)
    print(word_)
```